# How am I able to use some variables without initialization in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

In the below example how is the "arguments" variable working as it is never initialized .

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }
```

Comment: As you have set null safety(?) to it. and it must initialized before. So what is your exact question can you briefly explain?

Comment: It is calling `getArguments()` function of the parent class. You can use Ctrl/Cmd + Click to navigate to its declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This goes back to the basic Kotlin knowledge. The [safe call operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls) `?.` is there to specify that, if `arguments` is `null`, then `let {...}` will not be executed.

This is similar to what we do in Java:

```
if (arguments != null) {
    param1 = arguments.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
    param2 = arguments.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`arguments` is a property, not a variable. You can access properties of any ancestor class if they are not marked `private` or in some cases `internal`. In this case, the property is defined in a Java class. Java doesn't officially have properties, but Kotlin converts Java bean syntax into properties if the signatures are appropriate, [as explained here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters).

Since the superclass Fragment defined in Java has a `getArguments()` method, that is converted to a property named `arguments` in Kotlin code.

Comment: Not sure, but probably `arguments` is coming from the `Fragment` class and not the `Activity` class. `Activity` doesn't have any arguments.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks.